# How to change the angle for the CHEVRON shape

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to draw a chevron shape using Apache POI. I want to change the angle of the arrow in the end so that I can get more space for the text area. Currently the angle is almost at 45 degrees. I haven't found anything in the API documentation which can help me change the angle of the arrow edge.

```
ClientAnchor anchor = this.createClientAnchor(helper, x, y,a, b);
XSSFSimpleShape shape = ((XSSFDrawing) drawing).createSimpleShape((XSSFClientAnchor) anchor);
shape.setShapeType(ShapeTypes.CHEVRON);
shape.setLineWidth(1.5);
shape.setLineStyle(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a default shape of `ShapeTypes.CHEVRON` and look at this in `Excel` you will see a handle for setting the arrow's angle. Do manipulating it and then save the file and then simply unzip the `*.xlsx` file and have a look at `/xl/drawings/drawing1.xml`. There you will find

```
...
<a:prstGeom prst="chevron">
 <a:avLst>
  <a:gd name="adj" fmla="val 160000"/>
 </a:avLst>
</a:prstGeom>
...
```

So we need the `AvLst` which is a `CTGeomGuideList` and then we can manipulate the handle (`adj`) programmatically.

The only thing we must know additionally is what are the possible values for `val`. Some test settings leads to the insight that 0 is the adjust handle shifted maximum to right, which will lead to a rectangle shape. The position where the adjust handle is shifted maximum to left is `100,000 * cx / cy * 1` where `cx` is width and `cy` is height of the shape. All other adjust handle settings are between. So `100,000 * cx / cy * 0.5` will be having adjust handle shifted to middle.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateExcelShapes {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();

  XSSFDrawing drawing = (XSSFDrawing)sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
  XSSFClientAnchor anchor;
  XSSFSimpleShape shape;
  long cx;
  long cy;
  long adjustPos;

  //default chevron
  anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 6);
  shape = drawing.createSimpleShape(anchor);
  shape.setShapeType(ShapeTypes.CHEVRON);
  shape.getCTShape().getNvSpPr().getCNvPr().setId(0);
  shape.getCTShape().getNvSpPr().getCNvPr().setName("CHEVRON 1");
  shape.setLineWidth(1.5);
  shape.setLineStyle(0);
  shape.setLineStyleColor(0,0,0);

  //chevron having adjust handle shifted maximum to left (100%) - 0 == adjust handle shifted maximum to right == rectangle
  anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 5, 12);
  shape = drawing.createSimpleShape(anchor);
  shape.setShapeType(ShapeTypes.CHEVRON);
  shape.getCTShape().getNvSpPr().getCNvPr().setId(2);
  shape.getCTShape().getNvSpPr().getCNvPr().setName("CHEVRON 2");
  shape.setLineWidth(1.5);
  shape.setLineStyle(0);
  shape.setLineStyleColor(0,0,0);
  cx = Math.round(shape.getCTShape().getSpPr().getXfrm().getExt().getCx() * 1.142857143); //apache poi is not calculating cx properly, we are correcting it by factor 1.142857143
  cy = shape.getCTShape().getSpPr().getXfrm().getExt().getCy();
  adjustPos = Math.round(100000.0 * cx/cy * 1); //adjustment position 100%
  shape.getCTShape().getSpPr().getPrstGeom().getAvLst().addNewGd().setName("adj"); //adjustment
  shape.getCTShape().getSpPr().getPrstGeom().getAvLst().getGdArray(0).setFmla("val " + adjustPos); //adjustment position

  //chevron having adjust handle shifted to middle (50%)
  anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 14, 6, 18);
  shape = drawing.createSimpleShape(anchor);
  shape.setShapeType(ShapeTypes.CHEVRON);
  shape.getCTShape().getNvSpPr().getCNvPr().setId(4);
  shape.getCTShape().getNvSpPr().getCNvPr().setName("CHEVRON 3");
  shape.setLineWidth(1.5);
  shape.setLineStyle(0);
  shape.setLineStyleColor(0,0,0);
  cx = Math.round(shape.getCTShape().getSpPr().getXfrm().getExt().getCx() * 1.142857143);
  cy = shape.getCTShape().getSpPr().getXfrm().getExt().getCy();
  adjustPos = Math.round(100000.0 * cx/cy * 0.5); //adjustment position 50%
  shape.getCTShape().getSpPr().getPrstGeom().getAvLst().addNewGd().setName("adj"); //adjustment
  shape.getCTShape().getSpPr().getPrstGeom().getAvLst().getGdArray(0).setFmla("val " + adjustPos); //adjustment position

  wb.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelShapes.xlsx"));
  wb.close();

 }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Axel. That saved my day.